# Using ES6 in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I am planning to learn Vue.js , someone told me that I need to learn es6 to continue Vue.js , I asked so many people on this but I need more opinion , I appreciate a lot.

Comment: Asking for opinions is offtopic on SO. "ES6" is currently just an umbrella term for up-to-date JS. Considering the actual ES6 spec is 2015, you certainly don't want to stick to older standards without a reason. When using a framework, you need to know the language that is in use. It's not about JS or Vue, this is just a fact that is applicable to any situation. Language skills need to be at least the same as framework skills, otherwise very awkward problems will occur. Basically, you need to learn how to walk before you run to not injury yourself, because the former is more essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ESNext (meaning ES6, ES7, ES8 etc...) will be quite useful indeed.
Like arrows functions, `async/await` etc... It's not a requirement but it's a nice to have.
Vue.js supports it out of the box too.

Answer (score 0):

No. Only the browser that run the code cares about what version of JavaScript you use.